Can't run Spring Boot project through command line. Please add a 'mainClass' property error
Normally I use Intellij but today I'm trying to run my code through command line. This code is perfectly working in IDE but when I run it on command line it doesn't. I'm running the "mvn spring-boot:run" command on the pom.xml directory. And what annoys me most is it worked one time. Everything was same but then I played a bit spring boot version etc. and when I reversed it wasn't working anymore. And also how does Intellij run these codes without spring-boot? I have other projects without spring-boot on their pom.xml and they run flawlessly on intellij but don't work with "mvn spring-boot:run" command. What is the command that Intellij uses?
my folder strcuture is:
HelloWorld/src/main/java/Example.java
HelloWorld/pom.xml
my java version:
java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS
Here's the Example.java

import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Example{
@RequestMapping("/sayHello")
String sayHello(){
return "Hello World";
}

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class,args);
    }

}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>

Error
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------------< com.example:myproject >------------------------
[INFO] Building myproject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot:1.5.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ myproject >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\tahir\Desktop\HelloWorld\src\main\resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\tahir\Desktop\HelloWorld\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\tahir\Desktop\HelloWorld\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot:1.5.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ myproject <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot:1.5.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ myproject ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.093 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-13T20:03:57+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project myproject: Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

I tried almost anything I could find on the web when I wrote the error code.

Replace  @EnableAutoConfiguration with @SpringBootApplication and you should be fine

Try placing <build><plugins><plugin><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId></plugin></plugins></build> below the root node of pom.xml

Please take a look at the answer How do I tell Spring Boot which main class to use for the executable jar?
Also you can try to check your very first line on debugger/run window logs to recognize a command your IDE calls to start an app. Major part of the line would be a list of libraries that your IDE adds to runtime (for a comfortable start and for IDE purposes) but at the end of the line you would see a start command itself and compare with yours. It might help.
